# AWS S3 SDK creates folders with trailing forward slash

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I have googled this extensively and not found any post commenting on this problem.  Using the code below I upload a file to a path in AWS S3 which creates the new path and adds the file:
BucketName + NewFolderName + FileName

However, it adds a forward slash in the path as shown below.

[image]

The screenshot below shows the code I’m using and as you can see the “BucketName” property which contains the target path does not have the trailing forward slash.  Can someone please tell me why it adds this slash and how to prevent it?

[image]

Thank  you.

Comment: [Bucket names can consist only of lowercase letters, numbers, dots (.), and hyphens (-)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html).  Whatever value you have in `BucketName` is not in fact a bucket name.

Comment: @AnonCoward, if its not a bucket name, then what is it?  I see plenty of examples that use forward slashes to separate what looks like folder names such as this example:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/working-with-files-and-folders-in-s3-using-aws-sdk-for-net.  but these examples also create what appears in the console as a folder name with a forward slash.  Is the solution to just create the folder, then in another call add the file?

Comment: Set bucket name to `trb-test-bucket` and then the key to `testsubdir/whatever.txt`. You're putting the 'folder' in the wrong place, the bucket should not have any 'directory' info. Remember that you have a bucket & then objects with keys that can *simulate* folders.

Comment: Thank you @ErmiyaEskandary, I corrected that mistake but I still get a slash after the folder name in the S3 console.  Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

In AWS s3 everything is a key value pair. In the GUI (s3 dashboard) it is rendered so that you get the file system like structure. The trailing slash depicts that its a key prefix meaning there are multiple objects with that key prefix (equivalent of saying multiple files inside a **folder**).
If no trailing slash is there, that is the end of the key.

In your case "Bold2.png" is the end of the key string, whereas "testsubdir" is part of the key (substring not ending).